# Not able to Rerender the pageblockTable of vf page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Whenever I delete a record from the vf page, the pageblocktable should be rerendered. But I used javascript remoting to delete the record and  I am able to reload the page but not able to rerender the table after deletion.
I include the code below` TIA

```
<apex:page standardController="Campaign" extensions="CampaignMemberManagementController" >

 <apex:form id="form">
      <apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>
         <apex:pageblock id="block">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="list">
              <apex:actionStatus startText="Please wait...operation in progress"  id="deleteProgress">
                  <apex:facet name="start" >                     
                   <!-- <apex:image value="/img/loading.gif"/> -->
                   <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.Loading,'images/Chrysanthemum.png')}" width="50" height="50"/>               
                  </apex:facet>
              </apex:actionStatus>
              <apex:pageblocktable value="{!memberList}" var="ml"  rendered="true">                   
                  <apex:column >
                        <apex:commandLink onclick="deleteCampaignMember('{!ml.id}')" status="progress" reRender="list">Delete</apex:commandLink>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column value="{!ml.Name}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!ml.Type}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!ml.Association_Date__c}"/>
              </apex:pageblocktable> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>

<script>  

function askValidationPreference() {
    associationDate=document.getElementById('{!$Component.form.block.blocksection.date}').value;
    var yes=confirm("Do you want to validate the association date?");
    if(yes==true){
        alert(associationDate);
        check();                    
    }
    else{
        alert("askValidationPreference Not OK");
    } 
}  

function deleteCampaignMember(memberId) {
var sure=confirm("Are you Sure?");
    if(sure==true){
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.CampaignMemberManagementController.deleteMembers}',
            memberId, 
            function (result, event) {
                if (event.status){
                    location.reload();                       
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rerender wont work because you are calling the javascript function on command link click. and because its java script call rerender wont work. you can use the  action function like following :

VF page:

```
<apex:commandLink status="progress" onclick="deleteCampaignMember('{!ml.id}');" /> Delete</apex:commandLink>
<apex:actionFunction name="DodeleteCampaignMember" action="{!deleteMembers}"  rerender="list">

                    <apex:param name="p1" value="" assignTo="{!MemberId}"/>
                </apex:actionFunction>
```

Javascript :

```
   function deleteCampaignMember(memberId){

            DodeleteCampaignMember(memberId);

    }
```

this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `<apex:actionRegion >` for the command link or button like below...

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    //Your Command Link or Button
</apex:actionRegion>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can add an actionFunction which calls an empty method in controller and then rerenders the section you want.

This actionFunction can be called in the callback function of deleteMembers remote action call. This will rerender the section you provide when the remote action call is completed.